# Format string inplace in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I've notice I'm not manage to format string in-place when calling a function in PowerShell. I need to format it because I want to output a number as hex and not decimal.

This didn't work like so:

```
WriteLog "Running Step | Retry=$RetryCount | EnabledDevices={0:X}" -f $EnabledDevices
```

It only works if I store the result in variable and then use it like so:

```
$Log = "Running Step | Retry=$RetryCount | EnabledDevices={0:X}" -f $EnabledDevices
WriteLog $Log
```

If there a way to do it in one statement instead of two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put it in parentheses:

```
WriteLog ("Running Step | Retry=$RetryCount | EnabledDevices={0:X}" -f $EnabledDevices)
```